# how to ignore state of a Non-database column in a APEX report

Tags: oracle-apex

I have created a Master-Detail page. Detail region is a report region. 
Assume, master region records products manufactured and it's details.
Assume, detail region records list of employees involved (multiple rows) and their details.
For the sake of redundency EMPNO column is present in Detail Table, but not the EMP_NAME column.
My question is, I would like to show a non-database column EMP_NAME in detail region.  EMP_NAME holds value based on EMPNO column value (after querying EMP table).  How to achieve this?  Please help.  (I use Apex 4.2.6)

Thanks,
-Anand

Comment: @Ftaveras  
Let me give one more example.  Wanted to how it is done.  
For order management Master-Detail page, in the detail section there will be multiple products.  
Only PRODUCT_ID present in detail table.  
However, we show PRODUCT_NAME.  How it is achieved?  
By join query to PRODUCTS, we can get PRODUCT_NAME. Fine, it helps during navingating records.  
But what about adding new row?  How to show PRODUCT_NAME as soon as we select product ID. 
Can someone help please.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a scalar subquery column to the query:

```
select ...,
       (select emp_name from emp where emp.empno = det.empno) as emp_name
  from details det
   ...
```

APEX will make this a Display As Text column by default.

But if you want this to display the new for a new record as well, that isn't enough.  You could instead change the Display As attribute of the EMPNO column to Select List, and then define the LOV as

```
select ename, empno from emp order by ename
```

Now instead of typing in an EMPNO value and trying to get the name to appear in another column, the name will appear in the select list **instead of** the EMPNO.  Or you could show the EMPNO as well like this:

```
select empno||' - '||ename as d, empno from emp order by 1
```

Comment: As long as column property is "Display as Text (escape special char, does not save state)" it works.  
However, during add new record, I can't populate field EMP_NAME because it is display only.
If I make it "Text Field", I get error during navigation or add row.
"1 error has occurred•Current version of data in database has changed since user initiated update process..."

Comment: For time being let's ignore how I populate the column  
Assume that I will type the value.  
But how to change from Display to Text only during Add Record?  
In case if I make it Text field, will it not give error again when I try to save the record (earlier it was giving error while save when it was Text field)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: Let me give one more example.  Wanted to how it is done.
For order management Master-Detail page, in the detail section there will be multiple products.  
Only PRODUCT_ID present in detail table.  
However, we show PRODUCT_NAME.  How it is achieved?  
By join query to PRODUCTS, we can get PRODUCT_NAME. Fine, it helps during navingating records.  
But what about adding new row?  How to show PRODUCT_NAME as soon as we select product ID.

Comment: Use a select list?  That's what select lists do.

Answer (score 0):

You can subfix ignored column names with _NOSUBMIT. Your query will look like:

```
SELECT D.EMPNO
...
, EMP.EMP_NAME AS EMP_NAME_NOSUBMIT
, FROM ...
```

Apex will ignore nosubmit fields.

Comment: I added EMP_NAME column with EMP_NAME_NOSUBMIT.

Comment: I added EMP_NAME column with EMP_NAME_NOSUBMIT.  
I made column property "display as" to "Test Field". 
I used ajax call to populate its value after LOV selection of EMPNO.
But as soon as I submit page or even navigate records, I get below error -
"1 error has occurred•Current version of data in database has changed since user initiated update process..."

If I change column property "display as" to "Display as Text (escape special char, does not save state)"
It shows EMP_NAME when I navigate records.
But during add new record, can't populate EMP_NAME because it is display only.